# ZeroMQ and TCP Retransmits on Linux

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, zeromq, distributed-system

I'm having issues understanding what socket types are negatively impacted in the event that TCP must try retransmmitting messages.

We have a distributed system that uses a combination of inprocess and TCP connections for internal processes and external devices and applications. My concern is that in the event there is a significant traffic that causes latency and dropped packets, that a TCP retransmit will cause delay in the system.

What I'd like to avoid is an application that has messages compile in a queue waiting to be sent (via a single ZeroMQ TCP socket) because TCP is forcing the socket to repeatedly retransmit messages that never sent an acknowledge.

Is this an issue that can happen using ZeroMQ? Currently I am using PUSH/PULL on a Linux OS.

Or is this not a concern, and if not, why?

It is crucial that messages from the external devices/applications do not feed stale data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the only transport where retransmits are possible is TCP over an actual physical network. And then likely not on a LAN, as it's unlikely that Ethernet packets will go missing on a LAN.

TCP internal to a computer, and especially IPC, INPROC, etc will all have guaranteed delivery of data first time, every time. There is no retransmit mechanism.

If one of the transports being used by socket does experience delays due to transmission errors, that will slow things up. ZMQ cannot consider a message "sent" until it's been propagated via all the transports used by the socket. The external visibility of "sent" is that the outbound message queue has moved away from the high water mark by 1.

It's possible that any one single message will arrive sooner over IPC than TCP, and possible that message 2 will arrive over IPC before message 1 has arrived via TCP. But if you're relying on message timing / relative order, you shouldn't be using ZMQ in the first place; it's Actor model, not CSP.

EDIT For Frank

The difference between Actor and CSP is that the former is asynchronous, the latter is synchronous. Thus for Actor model, the sender has zero information as to when the receiver actually gets a message. For CSP, the sending / receiving is an execution rendevous - the send completes only when the receive is complete.

This can be remarkably useful. If in your system it makes no sense for A to instruct C to do something before (in time, not  just in A's code flow) instructing B, then you can do that with CSP (but not Actor model). That's because when A sends to B, B receives the message before A's send completes, freeing A to then send to C.

Unsurprisingly it's real time systems that benefit from CSP.

So consider ZMQ's Actor model with a mix of TCP, IPC and INPROC transports in ZMQ. There's a good chance that messages send via TCP will arrive a good deal later than messages sent through INPROC, even if they were sent first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've accepted it. Can you expand on the "Actor Model vs CSP" bit in an edit? And do you have any sources regarding TCP on a LAN or localhost?